# ggplot2 boxplots don't make any sense to me, why is this happening?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

So I have a dataframe, that goes like:

`time,candidate_id,allocation_id,final_score,position
data`...

Then I'm trying to make a ggplot2 boxplot.  I want this boxplot to have a different box for each `allocation_id`.  I tried to make one with:

```
ggplot(data=(allocation_info), aes(allocation_id, final_score))
```

but instead of getting multiple boxplots for each `allocation_id`, I just get a single giant boxplot.  Anybody know why this might be happening?

Comment: running the code you gave will not make a plot of any kind.  If you could add a portion of your data using `dput(head(allocation_info))` and show us the actual code you ran that resulted in the plot it would help.  However, you don't need to wrap the argument to `data` in parenthesis and I've found its better to be explicit in your `aes(...)` call, e.g. `aes(x=allocation_id, y=finalscore)`

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the group or colour aesthetic:

```
data(mpg)
ggplot(data=mpg) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=cyl, y=displ, group=cyl))
```

So for your specific dataset it will be something like:

```
ggplot(data=(allocation_info), aes(allocation_id, final_score)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(group=allocation_id))
```

Comment: You can also use `x=factor(cyl)`